# The role of the renormalization scale in the functional renormalization group

Tags: renormalization, regularization, non-perturbative

On p. 28 of Bertrand Delamotte's [Introduction to the Nonperturbative Renormalization Group](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0702365) he writes

> $k$ [the renormalization scale] acts as an infrared regulator (for $k \neq 0$) somewhat similar to a box of finite size $\sim k^{−1}$. Thus, for $k > 0$, there is no phase transition and thus no singularity in the free energy $\Gamma_k$. At finite $k$, everything is regular and can be power-expanded safely. We can therefore conclude that
>
> 1. the singularities of $\Gamma$ build up as $k$ is lowered and are thus smoothened by $k$ in $\Gamma_k$.
> 2. the precursor of the critical behavior should already show up at finite $k$ for $|q| \gg k$.

Could someone explain the analogy between $k$ as an infrared regulator and a box of finite size $\sim k^{−1}$?